# What are the pros and cons to hosting database VM and web VM on the same host machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubuntu, virtualization

I think I understand the cons to hosting a production database on the same machine as the web server that uses it. So, when it comes to dedicated machines, I always host db and web separately. But, I'm considering running Windows Server 2008 virtual machines on an ubuntu host. What are the pros and cons to running a database VM and a web VM on the same physical host machine?

The web server will always depend on the database server, so it doesn't matter that both machines might go down at the same time.

Ideally, our backup scheme would have something to do with backing up entire VM's at a time. In the same spirit, we envision being able to replicate the VM's on other host boxes to provide some fail-over.

We expect traffic to be low, but at the same time, we dont want to paint ourselves in a corner. I guess since VM's can be moved around with ease, the corner is almost non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

If the host goes down, you lose both machines; it's a single point of failure.

But really this question as it stands is hard to answer. If there isn't heavy utilization of the components, there really isn't much drawback as a hypothetical. If you're using this in a production environment where people rely on the services being available, you need to have plans in place for backups, for hardware failover or replacement, etc...you don't mention how vital these things are.

Is this a test system? Heavy use?...

On the plus side, separating them out at the beginning means you should be able to separate them to different hosts if it becomes necessary without re-engineering everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Pro: 
Cost. definitely. all hardware are somewhat shared. NIC, CPU, Memory etc.

Con: 
Both machine will be down on the same time if there is required reboot. However, this is a Pro too. DB may need to get up first before webapp. You can schedule to ensure DB boot up first before web to reduce app downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on load and if your writes need to be transaction-safe, you'll probably hit a disk I/O bottleneck if you're using the same underlying storage. You could use something like sysbench to stress-test MySQL and see what the world looks like under that condition, though.